# delete all values in a .csv file besides the name "EC_Customers" and "EC_Leads"

Tags: csv, sed

I have a .csv file that has a column for contact tags.

In this column, I have a whole bunch of separated tags.

I want to delete all of the tags besides "EC_Customers" and "EC_Leads"

How do I go about doing this? I have done a few searches, and I see sed and grep mentioned a lot, but I am not sure how to use them.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for [SU], it isn't really about programming since you mention the usage of `sed` and `grep` commands. Also note that your Q needs improvement (no source of the file).

Answer (score 0):

(without sample and nor structure info)

```
sed -e 's/EC_Customers.*EC_Leads//' YourFile
```

should a base to adapt to your structure of tag and field separator in csv